# How to calculate div height which is converted as image to fit the PDF using jsPDF & html2Canvas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I am converting div to image by using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

I want to calculate height of the div(in px) such that it will fit on the PDF page maintaining the aspect ratio of image
It should work on all window sizes(larger screens, IPAD, Desktop, laptop).

I am using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) for generating PDF

Here is the fiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/akshay1818/ys0z984x/51/

HTML Code

```
<div id="target">
    Set div height(in px) such that it will fit on the page maintaing the aspect ratio
</div>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to pdf</button>
```

JavaScript Code

```
window.takeScreenShot =function() {
      const layout = document.getElementById("target");
      const doc = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4");

       const canvasimg = html2canvas(layout).then(async(canvasimg)=>{
            let doc = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4");
            let img = canvasimg.toDataURL('image/png');
            const imgProps = doc.getImageProperties(img);
            const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
            var pdfPgHt = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
            const imgRatioHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
            doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, imgRatioHeight);
            doc.save('report.pdf');
       })
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Not yet @JimmyArroyo